# Is it possible to change with css the color of all svg paths at once?

Tags: css, animation, svg, lottie

I'm trying to change all the path colors of my svg at once, when I mouseover the div 'container':
"https://codepen.io/tiago-ascen-o/pen/dymeWoz"

Is it possible? Right now it only changes one color at a time and I need to mouse hover that path specifically

Thanks!!

Comment: Try `.container:hover path{
  fill: white;
}

.container:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}`

Comment: So simple, damn. Ahah, thanks, really appreciate!